# When parsing JSON, how can I make an array with only the top level element?

Tags: ios, json, swift

Using Alamofire and (trying to use) SwiftyJSON.

Let's say I have a JSON where at the "top level" I have two entries: TopEntry 1 and TopEntry 2. And then in each of those entries, I have a "title" and a "URL".

So it would look something like this:

```
{
TopEntry 1: {
      title: someTitle1
      URL: someURL1
        }
TopEntry 2: {
      title: someTitle2
      URL: someURL2
        }
}
```

If I just want to get the values of TopEntry 1 and TopEntry 2, how can I loop through this array and for each index (i=0, i=1, etc...) assign TopEntry 1, TopEntry 2, etc... to some NSMutableArray ?

I wrote the following code, which seems to do absolutely nothing useful:

```
let nodeIDArray : [String]
var nodeCounter : Int = 0 // My index
for nodeCounter in 0..<9 { // I know there are 10 elements, otherwise I would replace 9 with jsonValue.count , jsonValue being my JSON result
if let jsonValue = result.value {
nodeIDArray[nodeCounter] = jsonValue[nodeCounter].string
}
```

How can I make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I don't think you want to be assigning to jsonValue inside your loop.

Try to see if you understand the json structure by building some examples directly in code. Then experiment with accessing the results. Build up the samples to the complexity of your actual data.